# Cambio de clase boton React

Tags: reactjs

Hola estoy haciendo que un botón de menú para móvil haga una pequeña animación controlada por CSS en la cual este sera un componente, al momento de apretar sobre el boton el objeto state mediante onClick es actualizo a un estado. a traves de este creo un ternario dentro de el classname para que si este es true active las reglas del css. Al analizar por el inspector veo que el cambio en la clase responde favorablemente, sin embargo no toma las reglas de esa clase en particular por lo tanto, no me genera ningun tipo de cambio en el boton.

```
import React from 'react';

// Styles
import './styles.scss';

export class NavIcon extends React.Component {

state = {
    open: false
}

setOpen = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        open: !this.state.open
    })
    console.log('clicked', this.state.open);
}

render() {
    return(
        <div id="nav-icon" onClick={e => this.setOpen(e)}>
            <div className={(this.state.open) ? 'change' : ''} id="bar1"></div>
            <div className={(this.state.open) ? 'change' : ''} id="bar2"></div>
            <div className={(this.state.open) ? 'change' : ''} id="bar3"></div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

el scss:

```
#nav-icon {
float: right;
margin-top: .5rem;
margin-right: 1rem;
#bar1, #bar2, #bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
    .change > #bar1 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    }

    .change > #bar2 {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .change > #bar3 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Si especificas en sass que la clase debe ir concatenada al selector, debes usar `&`: `#bar { &.change > #bar1 { ... } }`.

Comment: Si se añade se modifican las clases originales (añadir / eliminar) y no observas el cambio esperado, el problema esta en el CSS, se aplica el estilo original que tiene mayor peso que el nuevo.

Comment: @gugadev desde hoy seras un jedi para mi jaja, gracias!